# Was there a live coding video on debugging Stack Overflow a few years ago?

Tags: discussion

I seem to remember there was a publicly available video of Stack Overflow developers chasing down bugs together; this was probably on Google Hangouts but I'm not sure. I've been searching for it for at least an hour but I can't seem to find it.

Did I dream it?

Does any of you remember anything like this?

If so does anybody have a link or reference to it?

Comment: Is it possible you're remembering a live Hangouts broadcast of a server/networking upgrade/install? I remember something like that from a few years ago.

Comment: @Undo I remember a developer reading logs to chase some specific bug but it wouldn't be the first time I misremember something.

Comment: Google "nick craver video" for hits.

Comment: This one maybe: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j5tOodr4ouc?

Comment: Too soon @rene, too soon!